# What is included in "background usage data"

Tags: android

[image: usage data screenshot]

What data is included in "background usage data"?

One of my app users reported that even when the app is in the background it uses more than 1 MB of data daily, which is quite large without even using the application.

In my application, I run a background service every 1 minute to get notifications which usually is an empty JSONArray unless there are any notifications.

Thinking this might have caused the data usage, I disabled the service and re-installed the app.

I don't have any Service running now, but still it shows 97.17 KB after 2 hours.

How can I reduce that usage?

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this could be that, you should decrease the number of service requests by increasing the service requests interval from 1 minute to 3 minutes.

And `background data usage` covers all those services that requires Data Connections. Some of them are Android update services, Email services, etc.

Comment: `Some of them are Android update services, Email services, etc.` They must not come under my application right?

Comment: No. Even your application services are also included in these services. See this http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/why-you-dont-need-third-party-apps-to-manage-background-data-use-in-android-jelly-bean/

Comment: Check this point in the link i commented before:Restrict Background Data: This option prevents all apps and services from using data in the background. Apps that depend on background data won’t work how you’d expect them to – for example, Gmail won’t automatically download new messages in the background if you enable this option.

Comment: `No. Even your application services are also included in these services` But I disabled all the services in my application and even now it shows 97.7 KB usage in background.